# Construct a weighted graph under the following conditions:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I need to construct a **weighted** graph of which neither of the *Greedy Algorithms* produces a correct answer to the *Traveling Salesman Problem*.

*Greedy Algorithms*

> 1) **Nearest Neighbor**
>   Works as follows: 
>   - First, choose any vertex as a starting point. 
>   - At each step, go to any of the smallest/closest (least weight) remaining vertices.
>   - Once *every* vertex has been visited, return home.
>   - *Repeat* with a new starting vertex **until** we've done this process for every vertex. 
>   2) **Cheapest Link**
>   Works as follows: 
>   - Choose the edge with *least* amount weight
>   - At each step, add the *next remaining edge* with the *least* amount of weight.
>  * Note, when picking smallest edges, we **do not** have to form a path.
>   * When picking edges, we **can not** pick an edge that would result in some vertex of degree 3.
>   * No unvisited vertices can remain.
>   - Stop when step 2 cannot be repeated *and* we have created a circuit.

We know that these algorithms *usually* give us the shortest possible path; however they are still estimations. I need to construct a weighted graph that demonstrates the fact that these two algorithms *aren't always correct*.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, taylor?

Answer (score 2):

Vertices A, B, C, D; all distances 2 except AC is 1 and BD is 100. Both algorithms will at some point use AC, which will force them to use BD, which is severely nonoptimal.

EDIT: The example above can't be realized in the Euclidean plane, but just make all distances 13, except AC is 10 and BD is 24. Again, each algorithm chooses AC, forcing it to choose BD, and to get a cycle of length 60, while 52 is optimal.